# Create a custom webpart for logging into web application

Tags: forms-authentication

I have a FBA based web application, where i want users to log in to the site using the custom page. So can someone help me with the source code that can be used i this

Comment: Please search well before posting your question here.. Check this link...https://customlogingpagefbasp13.codeplex.com/

Comment: If you are using SharePoint 2010 than look into it...https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2010/07/09/creating-a-custom-login-page-for-sharepoint-2010/